# JFace databinding Exception

Tags: data-binding, jface

I am new to Jface databinding. I am trying to poulate table using data binding. When any one clicks on row, vales are shown in mapped text field.When i do this i get Exception.("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find property with name name in class class com.swt.pro.model.Employee")Below is the class structure.

I have 3 Model class which are responsible for populating 1 GUI table

```
public class WorkplaceDetail extends AbstractModelObject {

private int code;
private String plant;
private String compRegNum;
private final List <Employee> m_employee = new ArrayList();
}

public class Employee extends AbstractModelObject{


private String empName;
private int empNumber;
private List<Address> address = new ArrayList();
}

public class Address extends AbstractModelObject{

private String primaryPhone;
private String secPhone;
}

In main class I am populating value of these models

List<WorkplaceDetail> m_workplace = new ArrayList();

public void initializeModels() {
m_workplace.add(new WorkplaceDetail(1,"IBM","12-02-033",));
WorkplaceDetail workplace= new WorkplaceDetail();
workplace.addEmployee(new Employee ("Prashant",0));
Employee employee= new Employee();
employee.addAddress(new Address("010-674634",null,"010-748347",null,null,null,null,null,null)); 
}

Databinding method

ObservableListContentProvider simpleTableViewerContentProviderList = new ObservableListContentProvider();
IObservableMap[] simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps = PojoObservables.observeMaps(simpleTableViewerContentProviderList.getKnownElements(), WorkplaceDetail.class, new String[]{"code","plant", "compRegNum"});
m_workplaceViewer.setLabelProvider(new ObservableMapLabelProvider(simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps)); 
m_workplaceViewer.setContentProvider(simpleTableViewerContentProviderList);

WritableList smListWritableList = new WritableList(m_workplace, WorkplaceDetail.class);
m_workplaceViewer.setInput(smListWritableList);

IObservableMap[] _simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps = PojoObservables.observeMaps(simpleTableViewerContentProviderList.getKnownElements(), Employee.class, new String[]{"name"});
m_workplaceViewer.setLabelProvider(new ObservableMapLabelProvider(_simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps));


IObservableMap[] simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps_2 = PojoObservables.observeMaps(simpleTableViewerContentProviderList.getKnownElements(), Address.class, new String[]{ "phone1", "phone2"});
m_workplaceViewer.setLabelProvider(new ObservableMapLabelProvider(simpleTableViewerLabelProviderMaps_2));
```

When i run this i get exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find property with name name in class class com.swt.pro.model.Employee"

Please help me to resolve the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your classes must follow [Java Beans](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) specification (note that this is different "Enterprise Java Beans" aka EJB). Basically, you need to add accessor methods (see section 7) and to support PropertyChangeListeners to inform the UI when your model is updated.

Comment: I have set the property in bean class, even then i get this exception " public void setEmpName(String emplName) { 
  Object oldValue = getEmpName();
  Object newValue = emplName;
  
     firePropertyChange("empName", oldValue, newValue);
 }"